# what is common applications for level-order traversal in binary tree?

Tags: java

I know some of the applications for preorder, postorder, and inorder traversal. But I did not know any applications for lever-order traversal. Could someone give me a simple application for lever-order traversal and describe it a bit?

Comment: Do you need to traverse the whole tree level X first, assuming the nodes on that level may have different ancestors?

Comment: Wikipedia states quite a list of applications: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Applications

Comment: @Jack Those applications only make sense for (directed) graphs in general, not trees, in the sense that on trees the problems solved are either trivial or non-existent or level-order traversal has no advantage wrt a dfs traversal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Level order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Queue-based_level_order_traversal) is actually a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) .
We visit **every node on a level before going to a lower level**.

So , to find nodes at a distance `X` units from a given `node` , you **don't need to travel full graph** (which can be very large ) ,
but just need to traverse all `nodes` at distance `<=X` , consider the case when `X` is very small compared to `height` of tree  .

Example : i can think of [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) .

Comment: BFS doesn't traverse the whole tree level, only the direct ancestors of some node. Nodes on the same level may have different ancestors.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev: yes you are right , but given a node , and if we want to find nodes at some distance from it , "without travelling whole tree " , BFS is the only way .